# How to make g++ refuse any code that exhibits undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, gcc, standards-compliance

I would like to add a `CXXFLAG` to my build systems that force the entire code-base to be well-defined. So every piece of code that exhibits undefined behaviour in a static fashion, should be refused by the compiler.

For instance `reinterpret_cast<A*>(someIntPtr)->aMember` is without any runtime context undefined (a), while `int i = bar(); i /= i;` could result in undefined behaviour (b) depending on the runtime evaluation of `bar()` (which could return zero).
I only expect the (a) cases to be caught, not necessarily the (b) cases.

Comment: Maybe it could catch `i /= i` too, since if it's not undefined behavior, it's just a silly way to say `i = 1`.

Comment: The answers to [A C++ implementation that detects undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7237963/2509) address what can be done with g++ in this direction.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: `i/i` is not a silliy way to say `1` because `i/i` is undefined iff `i == 0`. In all other cases, you are right, it is `1`.

Comment: @bitmask: Isn't that the gist of what I said?  *"if it's not undefined behavior"* i.e. *"except in the case where it is undefined behavior"* i.e. *"except when i is zero"*

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: Whoops, I overlooked the "*if*" which changes the meaning completely :)

Comment: With undefined behavior sanitizers the answer to this question changes a bit, although the are run-time checkers they catch a lot of non-trivial UB. Also constexpr can help a bit here depending on the use cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure that your goal is computationally feasible.

However, you'll get moderately close with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`; look at the other warning options to see what else you want to enable.

Comment: As @Kerrek has said, the compiler will miss many cases, but +1 to Jonathan for being constructive and giving the best options available. I would also run the program with valgrind to help detect any memory access troubles that do leak into the final executable.

Answer (score 6):

Impossible. There are many, many instances of UB which are not detectable. That's arguably the reason **why** they are UB, exactly *because* it is impossible to catch these problems at compile time.

Some examples:

- `int n = 0; std::cin >> n; ++n;` Signed overflow is UB. (Example of *value*-dependent UB.)
- `double d = std::sin(some_user_value); int n = d;` UB if `d` cannot be represented as an `int`. (Ditto.)
- compile multiple translation units with differing class definitions visible to each. (Example of UB due to limitations of the compilation model.)
- any race condition is by definition UB. (Example memory-model related UB.)
- misuse of variadic functions. (Example of UB due to the type system.)

Comment: Of course it's undecidable in general (halting problem). That's why I added the second paragraph; Detect all static cases.

Comment: "`int n; std::cin >> n; ++n;`" Without error checking, there is a potential for UB here, unless it can be assumed that the input operation succeeds.

Comment: Again, the error checking is missing, which is a programming error and can cause UB, unless you can assume that the formatted read operation succeeds.

Comment: @curiousguy: I fixed that by initializing `n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use static code analysis tools similar to the classic `lint`. You may already have [cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and you shouldn't rely on the compiler to point out UB for you.

You best bet is to use `-Werror` to cause all warnings to become errors, and [then enable a great deal of warnings.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)