# What features does gcc-4.9 Undefined Behavior Sanitizer have?

Tags: c++, gcc, undefined-behavior, gcc4.9, sanitizer

In [gcc-4.9 changes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html) it says:

> UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer (ubsan), a fast undefined behavior
>   detector, has been added and can be enabled via -fsanitize=undefined.
>   Various computations will be instrumented to detect undefined behavior
>   at runtime. UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer is currently available for the
>   C and C++ languages.

I looked at this question ([A C++ implementation that detects undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237963/a-c-implementation-that-detects-undefined-behavior/17979682#17979682)) but it seems fairly outdated.

This link (http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-06/msg00264.html) has some information on it, but it's several months old.

> This is an attempt to add the Undefined Behavior Sanitizer to GCC.
>   Note that it's very alpha version; so far it doesn't do that much, at
>   the moment it should handle division by zero cases, INT_MIN / -1, and
>   various shift cases (shifting by a negative value, shifting when
>   second operand is >= than TYPE_PRECISION (first_operand) and suchlike.
>   (On integer types, so far.)

From what I've read it's being ported to `gcc` from `LLVM`.

I've tried it with `(5 / 0)` and the only difference seems to be this output:

```
main.cpp:5:19: runtime error: division by zero
```

Does anyone have any more information on it or what features it has?

Comment: It seems like a lot of the ground work for this work would have to have been done in order to support [detecting undefined behavior in constant expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319413/why-do-constant-expressions-have-an-exclusion-for-undefined-behavior).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is more a framework for adding such checks than an attempt to detect all forms of undefined behavior (which is almost certainly impossible in the "halting problem" sense).

The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-fsanitize_003dundefined-652) lists these as the currently supported checks:

> `-fsanitize=undefined`
>   Enable UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer, a fast undefined behavior detector. Various computations will be instrumented
>   to detect undefined behavior at runtime. Current suboptions are:
>
> `-fsanitize=shift` This option enables checking that the result of a shift operation is not undefined. Note that what exactly is considered
>   undefined differs slightly between C and C++, as well as between ISO
>   C90 and C99, etc.
>
> `-fsanitize=integer-divide-by-zero` Detect integer division by zero as well as INT_MIN / -1 division.
>
> `-fsanitize=unreachable` With this option, the compiler will turn the __builtin_unreachable call into a diagnostics message call instead. When reaching the __builtin_unreachable call, the behavior is
>   undefined.
>
> `-fsanitize=vla-bound` This option instructs the compiler to check that the size of a variable length array is positive. This option does not
>   have any effect in -std=c++1y mode, as the standard requires the
>   exception be thrown instead.
>
> `-fsanitize=null` This option enables pointer checking. Particularly, the application built with this option turned on will issue an error
>   message when it tries to dereference a NULL pointer, or if a reference
>   (possibly an rvalue reference) is bound to a NULL pointer.
>
> `-fsanitize=return` This option enables return statement checking. Programs built with this option turned on will issue an error message
>   when the end of a non-void function is reached without actually
>   returning a value. This option works in C++ only.
>
> `-fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow` This option enables signed integer overflow checking. We check that the result of +, *, and both unary
>   and binary - does not overflow in the signed arithmetics. Note,
>   integer promotion rules must be taken into account. That is, the
>   following is not an overflow:
>
> ```
> signed char a = SCHAR_MAX;
> a++;
> ```
>
> While `-ftrapv` causes traps for signed overflows to be emitted, `-fsanitize=undefined` gives a diagnostic message. This
>   currently works only for the C family of languages.

Comment: it seems this text disappeared from the documentation page (as of 2016-01), any idea what's up?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky: Thanks. I have fixed the link to something (maybe) more permanent. Now the text does not quite match my excerpt, but I do not have time to fix it at the moment...

Comment: Does `-fsanitize=undefined` by itself enables all those sub-options or do I have to also pass them?

Comment: I was told on IRC `-fsanitize=undefined` enables all those sub-options.

Comment: Great answers +1 - I am trying to figure out if you need to enable all the sub-options to make this feature useful... I can't find information if these are all enabled by default. Do you know about that?

Answer (score 3):

Complete list of options listed in [UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html#ubsan-checks)

Latest GCC 5.0 additions extracted from [GCC 5 Release Series : Changes, New Features, and Fixes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html) listed below;

> UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer gained a few new sanitization options:
>
> ```
> -fsanitize=float-divide-by-zero: detect floating-point division by zero;
> -fsanitize=float-cast-overflow: check that the result of floating-point type to integer conversions do not overflow;
> -fsanitize=bounds: enable instrumentation of array bounds and detect out-of-bounds accesses;
> -fsanitize=alignment: enable alignment checking, detect various misaligned objects;
> -fsanitize=object-size: enable object size checking, detect various out-of-bounds accesses.
> -fsanitize=vptr: enable checking of C++ member function calls, member accesses and some conversions between pointers to base and derived classes, detect if the referenced object does not have the correct dynamic type.
> ```