# Are there any techniques to detect undefined behaviour with GCC?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Are there any command line options or techniques to make the GCC compiler report errors if the program does not behave in a predictable way according to the C++11 standard?

Comment: A good start is to compile with `-Wall -Werror`.

Comment: By "the program", you mean the compiler or the program you are writing?

Comment: GCC has [Undefined Behavior Sanitizer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738232/gcc-4-9-undefined-behavior-sanitizer).

Comment: This question isn't _too broad_. It's specific for GCC and asking about the _workings_ of programming tools certainly isn't off-topic! If anything else the question is a dupe of @LogicStuff's link.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ! Thank you for editing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ... to make the compiler to report some errors ...

Yes, there's a number of warnings do detect possible UB, and you can turn warnings into error using the `-Werror` option of GCC.

Also as mentioned in [@LogicStuff's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138123/are-there-any-techniques-to-detect-undefined-behaviour-with-gcc#comment57996401_35138123) GCC supports the [Undefined Behavior Sanitizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738232/gcc-4-9-undefined-behavior-sanitizer).

Though the better tools to detect UB are mostly Static Code Analysis tools, which can detect most of such defects.

You'll have to deal with false positives in any case though, and need to check your code again deeply.