# Pre Increment is not returning l-value

Tags: c++

```
// Pre-increment (or pre-decrement) 
#include <cstdio> 

int main() 
{ 
    int a = 10; 

    ++a = 20; // works 

    //printf("a = %d", ((++a)++)); 
    getchar(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

It is given in this article that `++a=20` works but when I am running on ideone, this code is giving an error.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-40/

https://ideone.com/12DmS7

Comment: What article? What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing `++a = 20`? Do you want 20, or 21?

Comment: *but when I am running on ideone, this code is giving an error.* – [C != C++ and C++ != C](https://ideone.com/1aZnHd). The article you link to is about C++. But you compile your code as C in ideone.

Comment: @John3136, the geeksforgeeks article, I have mentioned the link.

Comment: And what is the error message? Can you please copy it into the question!?

Comment: @WernerHenze The question is fubar. Read the comments.

Comment: Regardless of what language you use, you should never write an expression that modifies same variable twice.

Comment: not the answer: Nobody should write such code in the first place. You either want `a = 20;` or `a = 21;` so simply write that. Writing `++a = 20;` is fine for articles for geeks or to ponder about some rules of the language, but it should never pass a serious code review

Comment: It's probably to demonstrate that it's an lvalue.

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages! Do not confuse them!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The difference between C and C++ regarding the ++ operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654339/the-difference-between-c-and-c-regarding-the-operator)

Comment: I'm reminded of the initialism WYGIWYD: What You Get Is What You Deserve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one difference between C and C++.

In C, `++a` is **not** an *l-value*, so it can't be on the left hand side of an assignment.

In C++ it can be.

Some compilers that purportedly compile C code (e.g. MSVC) emit the construct in error.

Answer (score 1):

This code works well in **ideone** too(See the screenshot below). Run it using `C++` not `C`. Pre-increment works in `C++` but it gives a compilation error in `C`.

[image]