# Code executed after an error has occured

Tags: c++, crash, runtime-error

I have compiled and run the following C++ code with g++ version 4.8.2:

```
vector<int> ivec{0,1,2};
int& iref = ivec[1];
for (int i=3;i<100;++i)
   ivec.push_back(i);
iref = 10;
cerr<<"After Error"<<'\n';
return 0;
```

The program will crash as expected at line `iref = 10;`, because the reference is invalidated. But the string `"After Error"` gets printed. Why?

The answer to this question is important to me, because most of the time I use `cout` or `cerr` to find the line causing a run-time error.

Comment: Did you specify `-O0` on compilation?

Comment: I've tried that and It does not change anything.

Comment: What seems to be happening is that `iref = 10;` is corrupting the stack, but this does not cause a crash - you don't find out about it until `main()` tries to return. This explains why you see the debug output before the seg fault error message.

Comment: @PaulR Thank you for your answer. So, Should I use "cout" instead of "cerr" to track runtime-errors?

Comment: It won't make any difference - it's not uncommon for the effect of a bug to not show up until later (or maybe not even show up at all). This is typical of bugs that corrupt memory in some way - they are called latent bugs. Programmers typically use stress testing tools to flush out such bugs (e.g. valgrind).

Comment: @PaulR Thank you. Your answer was the most helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program has undefined behaviour because `push_back` invalidates the reference `iref`. The C++ standard does not specify *any* behaviour for the execution of your program. The question "why" cannot be answered in the context of C++.

Comment: So, how should we track runtime-errors caused by undefined behavior? should we use "cout" instead of "cerr"? (when I use "cout" the string does not get printed, which is probably because the output buffer is not flushed). I thought "cerr" was designed to help debugging process.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237963/a-c-implementation-that-detects-undefined-behavior this might provide some insight

Comment: @Ediac Thank you very much. I was looking for a tool to detect undefined behaviors (at least most of them).