# Detect UB like Rust

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, undefined-behavior, compiler-options

Two simplified examples:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Object{};

void use1(Object * o)
{
    (void)(o);
}

void use2(std::string & s)
{
    (void)(s);
}

int f1()
{
    Object * object_ptr{ nullptr };
    {
        Object object{};
        object_ptr = &object;
    }
    use1(object_ptr); // UB
    return rand();
}

int f2()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v{"foo", "bar"};
    auto & v_ref = v[0];
    v.emplace_back("baz");
    use2(v_ref); // UB
    return rand();
}

int main()
{
    return f1() + f2();
}
```

(`rand()` is just for testing.)

Rust just can not compile sources like this. With Clang or GCC (or maybe MSVC?) is there an option to detect such an undefined behavior?

Comment: Possible dupe/related: [A C++ implementation that detects undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237963/a-c-implementation-that-detects-undefined-behavior)

Comment: rust has *lifetime* in its type, c++ doesn't have it.

Comment: If you look at the mailing lists, a lifetime checker is currently on the way in clang static analyser: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2015-December/046653.html

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Just checking available tools: PVS-Studio can detect first UB (`V506 Pointer to local variable 'object' is stored outside the scope of this variable. Such a pointer will become invalid.`), but cannot detect second. Cppcheck also can detect first (`Dead pointer usage`), but cannot detect second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, no you can't. C++ is not like rust and give you the power of shooting yourself on the foot.

Fortunately, static analyser can detect errors for you. And with the clang static analyser, a lifetime checker is definitely on the way [link to the mailing list message](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2015-December/046653.html) and may suit your needs.

If you have memory errors, you can detect them with valgrind, it has been useful for me time to time.

Comment: Well, the MSVCs (2013) static analyzer doesn't find these sorts of errors, even when using "All Rules".